# App force closes on Google sign in button(On some devices)

Tags: android, google-signin

I published my app in beta testing, and a tester has reported that the app force closes when trying to sign in with google (no crash just closes the activity). I have taste my app on many devices and emulators and the bug did not occurred.

His device is running on android 7.1, and here is a [video](https://app.box.com/s/rbcihjp7c7qmna802gmx4ty60gz1zgwi) on what is exactly happening.

I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441373/app-closes-on-clicking-google-sign-in-button) but my Activity is not set as a SingleTask Activity.

I'm using 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'

This is my code:

-I call this in onCreate:

```
public GoogleLogIn(Activity activity, FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, DatabaseController db, DownloadInterface downloadInterface) {

    this.activity = activity;
    this.downloadInterface = downloadInterface;

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken(activity.getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .build();


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
            .enableAutoManage(fragmentActivity, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    this.db = db;
}
```

onButtonClick:

```
    showProgressDialog();
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
```

Handle sign in:

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        //mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean(AnalyticsHelper.AUTH_GOOGLE, true);
        AnalyticsHelper.logEvent(activity, AnalyticsHelper.AUTH_ACTION, bundle);

        getUserGoogle = new GetUserGoogle(activity, db, this);
        getUserGoogle.createUser(acct.getIdToken());


    } else {

        hideProgressDialog();
    }


}
```

Comment: please post logcat and handle `ActivityNotFoundException` in your code

Comment: I dont call a activity so do i need "ActivityNotFoundException" and i cant get logcat because it is not on my device it id on a device of a beta tester.

Comment: `activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);` might throw `ActivityNotFoundException` if applications on device doesn't handle that